# uwsgi application stops with error when running it with multi thread

Tags: python, multithreading, server, uwsgi

I am running a uwsgi application on my linux mint. it has does work with a database and shows it on my localhost. i run it on **127.0.0.1 IP** and **8080 port**. after that i want to test its performance by ab(apache benchmark).

when i run the app by command `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8080 --protocol=http -w wsgi` and get test of it, it works correctly but slowly.

so i want to run the app with more than one thread to speed up. so i use `--threads` option and command is `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8080 --protocol=http -w wsgi --threads 8` for example. 
but when i run ab to test it, after 2 or 3 request, my application stops with some errors and i don't know how to fix it. every time i run it, type of errors are different. some of errors are like these:

> (Traceback (most recent call last): 2014, 'Command Out of Sync')

or

> (Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./wsgi.py", line 13, in
>   application
>       return show_description(id)   File "./wsgi.py", line 53, in show_description
>       cursor.execute("select * from info where id = %s;" %id)   File "/home/mohammadhossein/myFirstApp/myappenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py",
>   line 166, in execute
>       result = self._query(query)   File "/home/mohammadhossein/myFirstApp/myappenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py",
>   line 322, in _query
>       conn.query(q)   File "/home/mohammadhossein/myFirstApp/myappenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 856, in query
>       self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered) 'Packet sequence number
>   wrong - got 1 expected 2',)   File
>   "/home/mohammadhossein/myFirstApp/myappenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 1057, in _read_query_result

or

> ('Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 2',) Traceback (most
>   recent call last):

or

> ('Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 2',) Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "./wsgi.py", line 13, in application
>       return show_description(id)   File "./wsgi.py", line 52, in show_description
>       cursor.execute('UPDATE info SET  views = views+1 WHERE id = %s;', id)   File
>   "/home/mohammadhossein/myFirstApp/myappenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py",
>   line 166, in execute
>       result = self._query(query)

Please help me how to run my uwsgi application wiht more than one thread safety. any help will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

it has solved.
the point is that you should create separate connection for each completely separate query to avoid missing data during each query execution